# Checked HTML from PHP

Tags: php, html

I have code:

```
<?php
    if ($user['x'] == 1) { $x_checked = ' checked'; } else { $x_checked = ''; }
    if ($user['y'] == 1) { $y_checked = ' checked'; } else { $y_checked = ''; }
    if ($user['a'] == 1) { $a_checked = ' checked'; } else { $a_checked = ''; }
    if ($user['b'] == 1) { $b_checked = ' checked'; } else { $b_checked = ''; }
    if ($user['c'] == 1) { $c_checked = ' checked'; } else { $c_checked = ''; }
    [...]

?>

    <input name="a" type="checkbox"<?php echo $a_checked; ?> />
    <input name="b" type="checkbox"<?php echo $b_checked; ?> />
    <input name="c" type="checkbox"<?php echo $c_checked; ?> />
    [...]
```

and i have too long code (others same lines). How shortcode to this?

Comment: I think you should re-think the overall design of your application. Can you give a short description of what you have and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is your actual requirement ?

Comment: make a loop for the `$user` variable obviously

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check in the input HTML:

```
<input name="a" type="checkbox" <?php echo ($user['a'] == 1) ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
<input name="b" type="checkbox" <?php echo ($user['b'] == 1) ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
<input name="c" type="checkbox" <?php echo ($user['c'] == 1) ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
```

If the values can only be `0` or `1` (or maybe more than `1` if you want that checked) then it is shorter:

```
<?php echo $user['c'] ? 'checked' : '' ?>
```

If you're going to have a `$user` element for each checkbox then loop it:

```
<?php foreach($user as $key => $val) { ?>
    <input name="<?php echo $key ?>" type="checkbox" <?php echo $val ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
<?php } ?>
```

From your comment it appears you may be echoing, if so then just:

```
foreach($user as $key => $val) {
    $checked = $val ? 'checked' : '';
    echo '<input name="'.$key.'" type="checkbox" '.$checked.'/>';
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but i have this html code in php echo '...';

---
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="a" '.$a_checked.' />';
----

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Foreach loops and arrays are in this case your best friends, this is how I usually do it.

```
<?php
$input_name = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

input_data = '';

foreach ($input_name as $value) {
  if ($user[$value] == 1) {
    $input_data .= '<input name="'.$value.'" type="checkbox" checked>';
  } else {
    $input_data .= '<input name="'.$value.'" type="checkbox">';
  }
}

 ?>
```

Echo the results in the HTML part:

```
 <?=$input_data?>
```

Comment: You need to initialize $input_data before foreach ($input_data = '';) - without this in first iteration you see a warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$fields = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'etc'
];

foreach ($fields as $field){
    if($user[$field] == 1){
        $checked = 'checked';
    }else{
        $checked = '';
    }
    print('<input name="'.$field.'" type="checkbox" '.$checked.' />');
}

?>
```